# JQuery Not Firing When Switching Pages Using React Router <Link>

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using a  To access different pages, when i go from my home page to my product page my hamburger button looks like it is clicked but doesnt open up. Also when i refresh the page it works again. So if i refresh the page and then click home it will redirect me home but then the hamburger button doesnt work again? I have included jquery using import $ from 'jquery' so i have no idea what it could be, here are my files below.

Javascript linking click:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import jquery from 'jquery'

$(document).ready(function () {
  //When hamburger button is clicked, open nav menu and pause carousel
  $('.navbar-toggler, navbar-collapse').on('click', function () {
    $('.mobilemenu, navbar-collapse').toggleClass('open')
  })

  //Shows the hamburger button when navbar is not open
  $('#hiddenToggler').on('click', function () {
    $('#hamburgerButton').show()
  })

  //Hides the hamburger button when navbar is open
  $('#hamburgerButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#hamburgerButton').hide()
  })
})
```

Example of Linking to product page

```
<Link to="/ProductPage/">
            <div className="card" key={product.id}>
              <div className="card-img-wrap">
                <img
                  className=" card-img-top"
                  src={product.img}
                  alt="Card image cap"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <h6 className="card-title text-center">{product.name}</h6>
                <p className="card-text text-center">
                  <small className="text-muted red">${product.price}</small>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
```

Css how navbar opens

```
.mobilemenu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    transition: all ease 0.25s;
    &.open {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
```

Comment: `$('.navbar-toggler, navbar-collapse')` there is a missing `.` dot in the second selector.

Comment: @Pain Good catch and i appreciate it but its still nto working :(

Comment: Also, a lot of people struggle to switch to a React mindset from jquery.  You dont normally need to directly manipulate the DOM like this. You can instead track the state of the toggle and adjust the rendered output appropriately.

Comment: @Pain Its like when i get redirected to a different page the (document).ready refuses to fire so when i click on the button none of the code underneath gets a chance to run.

Comment: @tmdesigned Thats probably the best thing i can do, do you have any good links to look into to set this up by chance?

Comment: https://medium.com/@wisecobbler/if-you-think-you-need-jquery-in-your-react-app-you-re-doing-it-wrong-77899ed7217e

Answer (score 0):

Facing same problem to me, I am used bootstrap cdn files in my project.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: So same thing is happening to you? Let me know if you find a fix, ill probably just use Reacts states instead of using Jquery but will mess around with it first.

Comment: I am fixed my problem by using  bootstrap cdn files directly instead of npm jQuery package.